# How do I allow a server and client to run on separate machines?

Tags: c++, server, client, port

I have created a client and server in C++. They are able to run on the same computer, but I need them to run on separate machines as well. Can the current code be used to accomplish this or would I need to edit it in some way?

Server code:

```
#define HOST_PORT "27015"

WSADATA wsaData;
int status;
struct addrinfo * data;
struct addrinfo hints;

WSAStartup(MAKEWORD(WINSOCK_MAJOR_VERSION, WINSOCK_MINOR_VERSION), &wsaData);

ZeroMemory(&hints, sizeof(hints));
hints.ai_family = AF_INET;
hints.ai_socktype = SOCK_STREAM;
hints.ai_protocol = IPPROTO_IP;
hints.ai_flags = AI_PASSIVE;

if (getaddrinfo(NULL, HOST_PORT, &hints, &data))
{
    std::cout << "Unable to translate host name to address\n";
    WSACleanup();
}
```

Client code:

```
#define DEFAULT_PORT "27015"

struct addrinfo hints;

ZeroMemory(&hints, sizeof(hints));
hints.ai_family = AF_UNSPEC;
hints.ai_socktype = SOCK_STREAM;
hints.ai_protocol = IPPROTO_TCP;

struct addrinfo *result = NULL;
int iResult = getaddrinfo(argv[1], DEFAULT_PORT, &hints, &result);

if (iResult != 0)
{
    std::cout << ("getaddrinfo failed with error: %d\n", iResult);
    WSACleanup();
}
```

Comment: I would've thought that this has more to do with your network configuration. Are the machines on the same local network? If not, is your server visible over the internet?

Comment: Its probably the network that needs configuring. For example if the server is behind a router you will need to setup port forwarding.

Comment: Well, if the server is reachable from your client box, and your name server config is OK, then, sure.  The IP lookup should suceed and the client connect up fine.  What errors do you get?

Comment: Step 1 - can you ping the server from the client?

Comment: @MohamadElghawi The client and server will be on the same network, but on two different machines.

Comment: Can you ping the other box by name, eg. 'ping MyServerName'

Comment: @MartinJames Ping the server? How would I do that? Would I give the server a specific host name and then have the client use that same name as the first `getaddrinfo` parameter instead of `argv[1]`?

Comment: lol, type it at your command line, eg. 'ping localhost' should get you a reply from yourself:)  'ping TheServerComputerName' should get you a reply from the peer.

Comment: A successful ping shows that the name resolution service is working, the other box is definitely reachable with the ICMP protocol, and, very likely, by TCP.  An error like 'Ping request could not find host' means that the name resolution failed to provide an IP address. An attempted, but failed, ping means that it's very likely that the other box is not reachable.

Comment: @MartinJames Okay, but how would I add the pinging functionality to the client's code so that it automatically attempts to connect to the server upon starting up? The server program name is "MusicServer", by the way.